# visual studio 2010 how to debug some code attached to a service

Tags: c#

i'm trying to debug some code attached to a service. this service has 2 .cs files implemented.
The main program calls a function for a remote object which has been initialized by the service:
string strCheminFile = DataLink.RemoteObject.CopyCaracMelToExcel(...);

the function is defined in the second .cs file of the service:

```
public string CopyCaracMelToExcel(...)
{
    CopyAlgomixToExcel copyCM = new CopyAlgomixToExcel(); 
    return copyCM.CopyCaracMelToExcel(...);
}
```

the function `CopyCaracMelToExcel` is implemented in another class library program

```
CopyCaracMelToExcel(...)
```

'implementation of the function'

this function is also declared into an interface file:

```
string CopyCaracMelToExcel(...;
```

when i try to debug the following step into main program:
string strCheminFile = DataLink.RemoteObject.CopyCaracMelToExcel(...);
i can enter interface file CopyCaracMelToExcel code but not the code in the class library program where the function is implemented.

i tried to attach the service as process into the debug menu. it doesn't work. also try to start the service as external application (into debug menu).

note: the service has two .cs file. only the main .cs has PDB file generated. the name of the second .cs file where the function is implemented doesn't have a pdb file and 
when i try to create a new breakpoint into this .cs file : the warning is : the breakpoint will not be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document

thanks a lot

Comment: Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Is the second class's code you are trying to debug running under the service's process or is it being spun up on its own? Is the cs code being invoked by a native (non-.Net) code? If the latter, you just need to set your debugger to mixed mode--- that is, native and managed when you attach to the service.

Comment: after all, i merged the two .cs files of the service and add the following command 'System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();'. And it works. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Debugger Launch method

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

**Edit:**

Have you tried these?

[debugging windows service gives No symbols have been loaded message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957720/debugging-windows-service-gives-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-message)

[VS 2010 doesn't load PDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178271/vs-2010-doesnt-load-pdb)

Comment: it doesn't work. indeed i can start the debugger for the first main .cs file of the service but i still can't access to the second .cs file where the function is implemented

Comment: i tried to insert my service's .pdb file into windows module but i got the following error message: a matching symbol file was not found in this folder

Comment: Have you tried stopping the service and performing a clean and rebuild all?

Comment: after all, i merged the two .cs files of the service and add the following command 'System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();'. And it works. Thanks to all